Ubuntu 24.04.01 unable to boot after installing latest updates. Stuck at hv-kvp-daemon.service
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS using kernel 6.8.0-48-generic. Yesterday I did apt update followed by apt upgrade and since then I am unable to boot to desktop. I did not check the packages list getting updated. So I am unaware if any hyper-v packages got updated.
Boot error

Initially the error was only about hyper-v (last two lines of screenshot). I performed kernel reinstall (from recovery console) by doing apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r) and since then I am getting gdm error.
Prior to kernel update I tried to backlist hyper-v modules
blacklist hv_vmbus
blacklist hv_storvsc
blacklist hv_netvsc
blacklist hv_balloon
blacklist hv_utils

in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hyperv.conf
the boot process still gets stuck
I also tried disabling hyper-v service. The boot process still gets stuck after gdm.service
From Recovery mode I ran dpkg. there were a few packages that it fixed, but it did not resolve my issue
Could you please assist me with the issue I am having?
some more info about my system (unsure if it will be relevant):
It is a dual boot system with Ubuntu and Fedora. grub loader is installed on Ubuntu HDD. Ubuntu and Fedora are installed on different hard drives. I swapped out DVD drive with HDD caddy and Ubuntu is running from there over SSD. I am having this setup for nearly 2+ years now and no hardware issues have been observed so far
Thank you in advance.

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

After multiple attempts and reading blogs, below answer helped me get my system back. Just reinstalled all the system packages and it worked
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^

https://askubuntu.com/a/1525026/2003089
